# Can not access images after convert their address from host to ip address

Tags: ios, web

Here is the situation. On the iOS, I used NSURLProtocol to intercept every single request from the webview. I was trying to intercept requests from a H5 page, so I can get requests of elements in the page, like images, js or css. Then I need to manipulate those links, the purpose is to avoid DNS spoofing.

To do so, I convert image request url format to IP address format. Take Google as example, The logo has address: https://www.google.com.hk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png. 
After conversion, I got address start with Google's IP address, http://216.58.197.110/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
In the Google's case, it is fine. I can load the image to the browser, however, It doesn't work in some other cases.

Here is another example, http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg. The converted URL is http://104.24.127.96/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg. Then this I got Direct IP access not allowed. I really think there are so many situations, like whether ports are open or not. Is a way to solve this?

Comment: You can't do `http:` in an iOS app...

Comment: @matt Yeah, I got error for http security warning, I walk around it by modify the plist. It works for now. But the reason is not https or http, you can try the url in your browser.

Comment: I see. So I guess as part of their security layer they also don't want you doing IP numbers.